# Displacement map to create terrain

Tags: unreal-4

I am trying to figure out the best way to create a procedurally generated terrain at runtime in Unreal Engine 4. For the moment, my idea is to generate a heightmap and apply it to a plane as a displacement map, since it sounds a lot simpler than trying to procedurally generate a mesh.

Is it how it is generally done? And if not, will I run into issues by doing it this way?

Comment: Your method sounds like it would work. Have you tried it already? In general there is no "best way" or how things are "generally" done. Most of the time, if it works, its an accepted solution. The best advice I could give is, try all the ideas that come to your mind, so if they fail, you will now why, but if they succeed, then there's not much else to do.

Comment: I did make a small test, and it looked like it could work, but before I start to work more seriously on this approach, I wanted to know if there were any serious drawbacks that I should know about.

Comment: Well the truth is... this is not the optimal solution for large landscapes. 
It is much better to extend the Landscape of UE4 and use it - it has many optimisations innate and will be broken in to quads - while rendering some quads and culling other quads - as well as material optimisations - each quad could have different shaders set on it - optimising the PSO.